# Starting and Stopping new Instance in Azure VM ScaleSet

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I have read somewhere that one of the XBox game uses Azure VMs Scaleset to run the game. Basically, one server instance will be created when any of the players have requested to play as a group. This server will be dedicated to their group alone until they finish the game. Once the game is completed Azure will release the instance and also stop the server. Until there is a need from other players, the instance will not be started. How can we implement such approach, when there is a job I need to create a new instance in my scale set and run my job in that. Also sometimes there will not be any users using the jobs, at this time I would like to stop all my instance (0 instances) to save the cost basically.

Comment: Are you looking for this command `az vmss stop --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myScaleSet --instance-ids 0`?

Comment: If the job is small, and if you require one instance per job, why not use containers instead of virtual machines (VMSS)?

Comment: HI Jason, I am more of a C# developer, how can we implement the command using a C# code?